# React navigation - navigate to default route after state update

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-navigation

I have a custom header component, with drop down lists, when I change my drop down list I dispatch `setYear` to update state, after this `react-navigation` sends me back to my homepage/ default route, even though I have used navigate and specified the same page. How can I change state and stay on the same page/ component view?

Custom header:

```
   onYearChange(e) {
      const { navigate, setYear } = this.props; 
      // dispatch action to change state
      setYear(e);

  }

  <View style={styles.alignMenu}>
      {this.state.year ? (
        <Picker
          selectedValue={year}
          label="Year"
          onChange={this.onYearChange}
          options={categories}
          style={styles.picker}
        />
      ) : (
        <View style={styles.alignMenu}>
          <TouchableHighlight
            onPress={() => this.show({ year: !this.state.year })}
          >
            <Text>
              {
                categories.find(category => {
                  return category.id == year;
                }).label
              }
            </Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
```

MapDispatchToProps:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    setGroup: (group, categories, year) =>
      dispatch(setGroup(group, categories, year)),
    setYear: year => dispatch(setYear(year)),
    setStudent: student => dispatch(setStudent(student)),
    navigate: route => dispatch(navigate(route))
  };
};
```

AppNavigator:

```
const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            header: false
        })
    },
    Month: {
        screen: Month
    },
    Day: {
        screen: Day
    }
});
```

`setYear` uses my `setCredentials` reducer to update credentials

```
export function setCredentials(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "SET_YEAR":
            return {
                ...state,
                year: action.year,
                student: 0
            };
        case "SET_STUDENT":
            return { ...state, student: action.student };
        case "SET_GROUP":
            const showStudent = !checkEmptyArray(action);
            return { ...state, group: action.group, showStudent };
        case "CLEAR_CREDENTIALS":
            return initialState;

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Using the credentials you set from a form on the `homescreen` or my `customheader`- I fetch all my data in my `month` view:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { year, group, student } = this.props.credentials;
    const Id = student || group || year;
    this.props.dispatch(fetchEvents(Id));
}
```

How can I dispatch my action `fetchEvents(Id)` in my header, after I change the `year` to update the data in my app?

Comment: Why do you need to navigate at all? If you're passing the event back using `setYear(e)` that should be all you need to do.

Comment: I don't know why it would keep changing my route for me, `setYear` does nothing with `react-navigation`. Right after I invoke `setYear` it navigates away from the page. Any ideas?

Comment: Tried to explain better, any ideas?

Comment: I don't have a great knowledge of Redux so I can't really be confident in my answers. In this scenario I would usually handle the state in the parent component and use the child only to pass information back the the parent state. Where you have `this.props.setYear(e)`, I would have a collection in the parent component like this `setYear={(e) => console.log(e)}`.